# django print referred url in view

Tags: django, django-views

In the following code how will i know there are two hyper links which are pointing to the same view.My question is in view how will i know which link the user is referring to? how can i get the referred url context in the view

JS:

```
window.location = "/project/server/fserver";
window.location = "/project/server/";
```

urls:

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^fserver/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

views

```
class IndexView(tables.DataTableView, VolumeTableMixIn):
    table_class = project_tables.VolumesTable
    template_name = 'project/server/index.html'

    def get_data(self):
        print "In get data==============="
        .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path

```
def get_data(self):
    print self.request.path
```

...you could also do this with a single url pattern

```
url(r'^(?:fserver/)?$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

or capturing as a kwarg passed to the view:

```
url(r'^((?P<page>fserver)/)?$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Answer (score 0):

An **Alternate** way is:

-> Add a class variable in you view to store the url name:

```
class IndexView(tables.DataTableView, VolumeTableMixIn):
   view_url_name = 'index'
   ........
```

-> Change the URL definition to following:

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^fserver/$', views.IndexView.as_view(view_url_name='index_fserver'), name='index_fserver'),
```

Also, this will help you get the url in more django-ish manner e.g. `reverse(view_url_name)`

Note: **Two different urls should never be of the same name**, as this creates ambiguity & After all the first matching name will be picked by Django so its of no use either.